# .ova files session error

Tags: linux, kali-linux

So i downloaded a Kali Linux .ova file for Oracle  VM VirtualBox.
I did download these in like 2-3 days so now i imported it to the vm. I got a error message when starting it.
Error Message:

```
Failed to open a session for
virtual machine Kali Linux
Details
Not in a hypervisor partition (HVP=0)
(VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).

VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes
(VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).



Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWarp
Interface: IConsole
           {872da645-4a9b-1727-
           bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Error Code: Failed to open a session for
virtual machine Kali Linux
Details
Not in a hypervisor partition (HVP=0)
(VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).

VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes
(VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).



Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWarp
Interface: IConsole
           {872da645-4a9b-1727-
           bee2-5585105b9eed} @Community

Comment: "VT-x is disabled in the BIOS". Solution, enable it in your motherboard firmware (ake UEFI is less then 10 years old, or BIOS for computers over a decade old).